# Sql server Update query from Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, function

I am trying to write a Sql query using excel function but i am getting function error i am new to ms excel can any one help me to fix this also please explain about escape characters in excel function -

Here is what i have written and getting error

```
   =CONCATENATE("UPDATE tbl_User SET ContactId=","'",B2,"'"," UserName=","'",E2,"'","Email=","'",E2,"'"," WHERE UserName=","'",D2,"')
```

TIA -

Comment: It looks like you are simply missing the last double quote from the formula and the commas for SQL between field names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@jbarker2160 got it in the comments: you are missing a quotation mark at the end, and your SQL query needs to have commas between the field names.  Posting the formula, since I wrote it up before seeing the comments: if jbarker2160 wants to do the same, please mark his answer as correct.

`=CONCATENATE("UPDATE tbl_User SET ContactId=","'",B2,"'",", UserName=","'",E2,"'",", Email=","'",E2,"'"," WHERE UserName=","'",D2,"'")`